# Win7 64bit & VB6 Active Reports Image issue

Tags: vb6, report, windows-7-x64, activereports

We have a legacy vb6 program using Active Reports 2.  We have been running on a mix of OS's from xp sp2 to Win7 64bit.  We have everything working except on one specific machine.  This machine (win7 64bit), when displaying certain active reports report, the back ground image is not stretching to fill the page like expected.  I've check all of the in house software installation and dll versions to see if something was not installed, but I cannot find anything different.  I'm starting to think it must be a low level dependency of Active Reports 2 but I cannot find that either.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try to further trouble shoot the issue?

Comment: Custom DPI? In win7 it's much simpler to change to custom DPI besides "small fonts" and "large fonts" previous version used to have.

Comment: That was it!  I never even considered that could be an issue, thank you very much.

Comment: @wqw, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the Answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: To be crystal clear, @wqw's comment lead me to check the dpi settings for that machine.  The dpi setting was not the default 96, once I changed it back and rebooted, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom DPI? In win7 it's much simpler to change to custom DPI besides "small fonts" and "large fonts" previous version used to have.